# ¿Cómo encuentro las palabras en una cadena que tienen el mismo número de vocales y consonantes y obtengo su número de orden en la cadena?

Tags: python

Tengo esta Cadena:

> *So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure  of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and  picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.*

¿Cómo encuentro las palabras en esta cadena, que tienen el mismo número de vocales y consonantes y obtengo su número de orden en la cadena?

Es decir, necesito encontrar las palabras que tengan igual número de vocales y consonantes. Por ejemplo: amor (2 vocales y 2 consonantes).

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no demuestra esfuerzo por parte del autor de la pregunta. No hay código que se haya intentado ni nada parecido

Comment: ...Y por cierto la pregunta no esta en inglés, solo la cadena y es irrelevante para resolver el problema

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código que has intentado y el resultado esperado para que alguien pueda probar **su correción** de **tu código**?

Comment: @JoséGregorioCalderón si es una tarea o no, no es relevante. Siempre y cuando sea una pregunta bien formulada es bienvenida

Comment: Postea tus intentos y una duda especifica para que no parezca que quieres que hagan el trabajo por ti.

Answer (score 3):

[Divide y vencerás](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_divide_y_vencer%C3%A1s). El problema es más fácil de resolver si lo divides en subproblemas menores más fáciles de resolver individualmente.

```
def divideEnPalabras( frase ):
  # codigo
  return listaPalabras

def tieneMismasConsonantesQueVocales( palabra ):
  # codigo
  return True # o False

def posicionDePalabraEnLista( palabra, lista ):
  # codigo
  return posicion

frase = ( 'So she was considering in her own mind, '
          'as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very '
          'sleepy and stupid, whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain '
          'would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, '
          'when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.' )
lista = divideEnPalabras( frase )
for palabra in lista:
  if ( tieneMismasConsonantesQueVocales( palabra ) ):
    print( palabra + ' - ' + str( posicionDePalabraEnLista( palabra, lista ) ) )
```

Ahora te falta completar cada uno de los subproblemas.
**Inténtalo**.
Y si con alguna te atascas puedes formular otra pregunta en StackOverflow. Pero dedícale un poco de tiempo a cada una y prueba a escribir algo de código. Si no funciona pon el código que no funciona en tu pregunta. Eso hará que recibas más y mejores respuestas.

Comment: Le agradezco a quien ha votado negativo su interés en esta respuesta. ¿Podría indicar, por favor, qué es lo que piensa que está mal?