# ¿Cómo ordenar las palabras de una cadena en forma descendente?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

¿Cómo se puede ordenar una cadena (string) en forma descendente, es decir, desde la palabra más larga a la más corta?

Note que para dos o más palabras cuyas longitudes son iguales, el orden de las mismas en la salida debe ser alfabético, pero sin sensibilidad a mayúsculas/minúsculas, como se puede observar en la salida del ejemplo.

Por ejemplo, al ingresar la siguiente cadena:

```
"Yo soy principiante en programación"
```

Debería producirse la siguiente salida:

```
"principiante programación soy en Yo"
```

Comment: Pues de una manera similar a esta pregunta similar hecha por una persona con un nombre similar al tuyo : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1729/c%C3%B3mo-encuentro-las-palabras-en-una-cadena-que-tienen-el-mismo-numero-de-vocale/1759#1759

Comment: Si, pero ahora necesito hacerlo en c++, y estos lenguajes son muy diferentes

Comment: ¿Son Nasver y Nazver la misma persona? No está en contra de las reglas el tener dos cuentas, pero hay pocos motivos para hacerlo y está desaconsejado. A tu pregunta le falta detalle. ¿Quieres ordenar un std::string o un const char* u otro tipo de cadena?

Comment: No la primera no es cuenta registra. Una string, por ejemplo                      string: Yo soy principiante en programacion                                                       out: principiante programacion soy yo

Comment: Tus dos cuentas pueden combinarse, fijate aqui http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Nasver y de acuerdo a tu necesidad, ¿Dónde debería quedar la palabra "en"? ¿Debe desaparecer de la salida? ¿Debe quedar antes de "Yo"? ¿Debe quedar después de "Yo"?

Comment: antes de yo, olvide de colocarla

Comment: @Nasver según tu respuesta a mi comentario, ¿Es correcto afirmar que para dos o más palabras con igual longitud, el orden de las mismas debe ser alfabético, pero sin sensibilidad a mayúsculas/minúsculas?

Comment: Si, sin sensibilidad a mayusculas/minusculas

Comment: @Nasver OK, edito tu pregunta con esta consideración.

Answer (score 3):

Para separar las palabras puedes hacer uso de la clase `istringstream` y de los iteradores `istream_iterator`.

Una vez has extraído las palabras del `string` en un `vector` es muy sencillo ordenarlas. En este caso he optado por una función propia en vez de una `lambda` por legibilidad, pero se podría integrar en una `lambda` sin problemas.

Para rematar la jugada falta volcar el contenido a la consola. Para eso se puede hacer uso del iterador `ostream_iterator`. Da la casualidad que este iterador admite un delimitador, lo que simplifica el proceso. Llegados a este punto únicamente falta por decidir si queremos volcar el resultado directamente a la consola o si es preferible almacenarlo en un string.

```
bool ordenarPalabras(std::string p1, std::string p2)
{
  if( p1.size() != p2.size() )
    return p1.size() > p2.size();
  else
  {
    std::transform(p1.begin(),p1.end(),p1.begin(),::tolower);
    std::transform(p2.begin(),p2.end(),p2.begin(),::tolower);
    return p1 < p2;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::string cadena = "Yo soy principiante en programación";
  std::istringstream stringStream(cadena);
  std::vector<std::string> palabras;

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stringStream),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::back_inserter(palabras));

  std::sort(palabras.begin(),palabras.end(),ordenarPalabras);

  // Para volcarlo directamente a la consola    
  std::copy(palabras.begin(), palabras.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

  // Para almacenarlo en un string
  std::ostringstream outStream;
  std::copy(palabras.begin(), palabras.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outStream, " "));
  std::string resultado = outStream.str();
  std::cout << resultado << std::endl;
}
```

EDITO: Al ejecutar el código verás que *programación* la pone antes que *principiante*. Esto es debido a que las palabras acentuadas no forman parte de la tabla ASCII. Para trabajar con acentos deberías plantearte usar `wstring` en vez de `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Usa [`std::sort`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Para poder usarlo, copia palabra a palabra tu cadena en una colección de palabras y ordena dicha colección:

```
// Creamos un lector de cadenas.
stringstream lector("Yo soy principiante en programación");
// Copiamos las cadenas en un vector de cadenas
vector<string> palabras{istream_iterator<string>(lector), istream_iterator<string>()};
// Ordenamos
sort(palabras.begin(), palabras.end());
```

Aquí tienes una <kbd>[demostración del código](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VstKbkkKdW8vtMXt)</kbd>.

#### Editado

Confundí ordenar alfabéticamente por ordenar por longitud; pero la respuesta sigue siendo válida: `std::sort` pero con una lambda.

```
// Ordenamos
sort(palabras.begin(), palabras.end(),
     [](const string &i, const string &d)
     { return i.length() == d.length() ? i > d : i.length() > d.length(); });
```

Mi respuesta es muy parecida a la de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) pero algo más compacta.

Aquí tienes una <kbd>[demostración del código](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PN0qgph28ztHQcTc)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo he hecho en Linux. Pero con C++98, con lo que debiera funcionar en Visual Studio.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void divide(const char* cadena, vector<string>& dividida) {
    const char *p = cadena;
    for (;;) {
        // Recorrer espacios
        while (*p == ' ' && *p != '\0')
            ++p;
        if (*p == '\0')
            return;
        const char* inicio = p;
        // Recorrer no espacios
        while (*p != ' ' && *p != '\0')
            ++p;
        dividida.push_back(string(inicio, p)); // insertar
    }
}

bool compara(string a, string b) {
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return true;
    else if (a.length() < b.length())
        return false;
    else {
        string::size_type tam = a.length();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
        {
            char minusA = tolower(a[i]);
            char minusB = tolower(b[i]);
            if ( minusA < minusB )
                return true;
            else if ( minusA > minusB )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

void ordena(vector<string>& palabras) {
    sort(palabras.begin(), palabras.end(), compara);
}

char* une ( const vector<string>& palabras )
{
    string::size_type tam = 0;
    vector<string>::const_iterator it = palabras.begin();
    for ( ; it!=palabras.end(); ++it )
        tam += it->length() + 1;
    char* resultado = new char[tam];
    char* p = resultado;
    for ( it = palabras.begin(); it!=palabras.end(); ++it )
    {
        memcpy( p, it->c_str(), it->length() );
        p += it->length();
        *p = ' ';
        ++p;
    }
    --p;
    *p='\0';
    return resultado;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char* cadena = "Yo soy principiante en programación";
    vector<string> dividida;
    divide(cadena, dividida);
    ordena( dividida );
    char* ordenada = une( dividida );
    cout << ordenada;
    delete []ordenada;
}
```

El programa se divide en tres partes :

- divide : a partir de la cadena de entrada crea un `vector` de `std::string` con las palabras separadas.
- ordena : ordena las palabras de mayor a menor usando `std::sort`; con una función de comparación creada para este caso que compara las cadenas según el criterio indicado.
- une : que reserva memoria para una cadena de longitud apropiada y escribe todas las palabras en esa memoria separándolas por espacios. Importante hacer `delete` de la cadena devuelta. Yo preferiría devolver un `std::string` en vez de un `char*` para no tener que ir manejando gestión de memoria, pero la redacción de la pregunta me hace pensar que debe ser un `char*`.

Cada una de esas partes debiera ser lo suficientemente sencilla como para explicarse por si misma.